# Windows 8.1 tablet BLE sample

Tags: windows-8, win-universal-app, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any working Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) sample for Windows 8.1 tablet?

I can found working sample for Windows phone 8.1 devices. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95)? It is able to run on both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. The sample shows how to interact with a Bluetooth LE device- reading, writing, and requesting notifications from the device's Gatt Server.